# How to write OAuth client for web elgg services

Tags: web-services, elgg

I am new to elgg and web development. I searched in net but did not get any working sample on OAuth and elgg web services example. So posting here my question.

I am using -

Elgg: 1.8.19
Web services plug-in: https://github.com/markharding/elgg-web-services
OAuth plug-in: http://community.elgg.org/plugins/385119/0.10.5/oauth
My problem is I did not find any tutorial or example on how to use OAuth client in Javascript. I am developing a Chrome Extension and from that extension I want to use Elgg web service.

Please suggest any link or steps or advice if I can use OAuth and Elgg Web service from Web Browser extension.

Thank you